# Spring integration FTP Server replied with: 426 Transfer failed

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I am currently working on spring integration with FTP support.

I made a transfer from local directory to a remote FTP server, But I am getting **Server replied with: 426 Transfer failed** error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to write to '/4001/in/temp/V31406_200000_120001.writing' while uploading the file; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Failed to write to '/4001/in/temp/V31406_200000_120001.writing'. Server replied with: 426 Transfer failed

       at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.sendFileToRemoteDirectory(RemoteFileTemplate.java:592)
       at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.lambda$send$0(RemoteFileTemplate.java:319)
```

Below is my session factory code.

```
@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultFtpSessionFactory ftpSessionFactory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    ftpSessionFactory.setHost(ftpHost);
    ftpSessionFactory.setPort(ftpPort);
    ftpSessionFactory.setUsername(ftpUser);
    ftpSessionFactory.setPassword(ftpPasword);

    LOGGER.info("ftpHost : {}  ftpPort: {}  ftpUser: {} ftpPasword: {} ", ftpHost, ftpPort, ftpUser, ftpPasword);

    ftpSessionFactory.setClientMode(0);

    return new CachingSessionFactory<FTPFile>(ftpSessionFactory, 10);
}
```

Comment: Try with `ftpSessionFactory.setClientMode(2);` - see it JavaDocs.

Comment: Thank you @ArtemBilan for the response, if I tried ftpSessionFactory.setClientMode(2), then i am getting Connection timed error.    Below is error logs.                                                                                        
  Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to write to '/4001/in/temp/V324008_200000_120001.writing' while uploading the file; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)

Comment: Try to play with `defaultTimeout` and `dataTimeout` options. There is really not too much Spring Integration can do for you. You indeed need to consult with your FTP server vendor for the best set of options to configure on the client to perform transfer successfully.

Comment: 4xx is designated a "transient" error and should be retried (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes); perhaps you have a flaky network. Check the server logs and/or run a WireShark trace on the network.